# Add frequency to transformation table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following dataframe:

```
> data6
                                 verb_object SESSION_ID
1:   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT   41595370
2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE   41595371
3:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
4:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE   41595282
5: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE   41595373
6:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT   41595368
```

I have a transformation table:

```
> u1
                                      items newitem
1   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT     OV1
2 BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE     OV2
3   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE     OV3
4 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE     OV4
5   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT     OV5
```

I would like to add to the transformation table (u1) the frequency of items in the original dataframe (data6).
In this case I would the result of u1 to be:

```
> u1
                                      items newitem  freq
1   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT     OV1    0.1667
2 BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE     OV2    0.1667
3   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE     OV3    0.3333
4 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE     OV4    0.1667
5   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT     OV5    0.1667
```

Here is the benchmark for the both offered solutions:

```
> microbenchmark(
+   setDT(u100)[setDT(data100)[, .(freq = .N/nrow(data100)), by = verb_object], on=c("items"="verb_object")],
+   
+   merge(u100, xtabs(~ verb_object, data100)/length(data100$verb_object) , 
+         by.x = "items", by.y = "verb_object", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE),
+   times=1000
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                         expr
                              setDT(u100)[setDT(data100)[, .(freq = .N/nrow(data100)), by = verb_object],      on = c(items = "verb_object")]
 merge(u100, xtabs(~verb_object, data100)/length(data100$verb_object),      by.x = "items", by.y = "verb_object", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 1.269799 1.394808 1.586311 1.439762 1.493543 66.58702  1000  a 
 1.842091 2.030118 2.634712 2.099499 2.182838 67.77471  1000   b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(u1)[setDT(data6)[, .(freq = .N/nrow(data6)), by = verb_object],
          on=c("items"="verb_object")]
```

which gives:

> ```
>                                        items newitem      freq
> 1:   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT     OV1 0.1666667
> 2: BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE     OV2 0.1666667
> 3:   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE     OV3 0.3333333
> 4: 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE     OV4 0.1666667
> 5:   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT     OV5 0.1666667
> ```

Comment: Why do I get the following error:> setDT(u1)[setDT(data6)[, .(freq = .N/nrow(data6)), by = verb_object], on=c("items"="verb_object")]
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(u1), setDT(data6)[, .(freq = .N/nrow(data6)),  : 
  unused argument (on = c(items = "verb_object"))

Comment: @Avi You are probably using an old version of *data.table*. You need *v1.9.6*

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
merge(u1, xtabs(~ verb_object, data6)/length(data6$verb_object), 
      by.x = "items", by.y = "verb_object", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
                                     items newitem      Freq
1   BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT     OV1 0.1666667
2 BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE     OV2 0.1666667
3   26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE     OV3 0.3333333
4 2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE     OV4 0.1666667
5   6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT     OV5 0.1666667
```

Data:

```
data6 <- structure(list(verb_object = c("BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT", 
"BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE", "26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE", 
"26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE", "2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE", 
"6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT"), SESSION_ID = c(41595370L, 
41595371L, 41595282L, 41595282L, 41595373L, 41595368L)), .Names = c("verb_object", 
"SESSION_ID"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")   

u1 <- structure(list(items = c("BA31C1CC63E5043483FAE25F085E25E5 INSERT", 
"BECE6374D91D47E6285EFDEBA6D65BB9 DATABASE", "26D695C8CA82CAFFDF985201F3AA44D7 UPDATE", 
"2BC5A4199A0DDA16FA17A9CA1AA17C02 DATABASE", "6D944D54C54ED75D487288FE1505BB59 INSERT"
), newitem = structure(1:5, .Label = c("OV1", "OV2", "OV3", "OV4", 
"OV5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("items", "newitem"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It will be a good idea to compare between the two alternative from efficiency perspective since there is need to run it in big data.

Comment: @Avi For use on large datasets, the *data.table* method is highly probably the fastest one.

Comment: Why do I get the following error: > merge(u1, xtabs(~ verb_object, data6)/length(data6$verb_object) , 
+       by.x = "items", by.y = "verb_object", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
Error in merge.data.table(u1, xtabs(~verb_object, data6)/length(data6$verb_object),  : 
  Can not match keys in x and y to automatically determine appropriate `by` parameter. Please set `by` value explicitly.

Comment: @Avi Probably because you have loaded the data.table package and R is using the function `merge` from that package and not the function `merge`  with the same name in the base package. Try to detach data.table and run the code again.

Comment: Now I get for each row in Freq the value  NA

Comment: @Avi I added the data frames I used in my answer. I ran my code using those two data frames without any problem. Try using them and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: @mpalanco works perfect! Thanks a lot! I wonder if you can help me with the above solution error of Jaap.

Comment: @Avi Updating *data.table* to the latest version didn't help?

Comment: Worked! Now both are working! Thank you mpalanco and Jaap!

Comment: @Jaap you are right about performance: > microbenchmark of the first is your solution:
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 1.269799 1.394808 1.586311 1.439762 1.493543 66.58702  1000  a 
 1.842091 2.030118 2.634712 2.099499 2.182838 67.77471  1000   b